# Rails - Enable deep merge for config_for method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, config

I am currently trying to load a .yml config file like this:

```
settings = Rails.application.config_for(:file_name)
```

This file looks similar to this:

```
shared:
  variable_1:
    variable_1_a: something
    variable_1_b: something
  variable_2: example

development:
  variable_1:
    variable_1_a: something else
```

However it does not load using deep merge instead only this is loaded:

```
settings => {
  variable_1 => {
    variable_1_a => 'something else'
  }
  variable_2 => 'example'
}
```

Is there a way to also include 'variable_1_b' for the config_for method?

EDIT:
Apparently I am using an old version of rails since this behavior was changed in this rails 6.1+ commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4d858b3f2a70aefda741c517c2db61b4d7d4adfb#diff-84292fcaae327f1a70e7c3b1ebb55b193dea016c1118a8566930bc5cd2a51ba5

This means that updating the rails version solved the issue for me.

Comment: There is no `variable_2_b` in your example. Also, to be able to reproduce this, please add your specific code you are using to merge the two hashes, including concrete demo data showing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. In fact, this works perfectly on my machine:

**./config/file_name.yml**

```
shared:
  variable_1:
    variable_1_a: something
    variable_1_b: something
  variable_2: example

development:
  variable_1:
    variable_1_a: something else
```

Rails console (whitespace added for clarity):

```
Rails.application.config_for(:file_name)
=> {
    :variable_1 => {
      :variable_1_a => "something else",
      :variable_1_b=>"something"
    },
    :variable_2=>"example"
  }
```

Furthermore, [this behaves exactly as described in the rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-config_for).

Therefore I am voting to close your question, barring some key additional information missing from your post.